# SAS retain statement not working as I hoped

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset

```
data have;
input SUBJID VISIT$ PARAMN  ABLF$ AVAL;
cards;
        1   screen      1   .       151
        1   random      1   YES     .
        1   visit1      1   .       .
        1   screen      2   .       65.5
        1   random      2   YES     65      
        1   visit1      2   .       .
        1   screen      3   .       .
        1   random      3   YES     400
        1   visit1      3   .       420
;
run;
```

I want to create another variable called `BASE` that captures the value of `AVAL` (when there is an actual value in place) when `ABLF=YES` and and then drag it down until a new `PARAMN` is encountered.

Basically I want the output to look like this

```
 SUBJID  VISIT$  PARAMN  ABLF$  AVAL BASE;

    1   screen      1   .       151     .
    1   random      1   YES     .       .
    1   visit1      1   .       .       .
    1   screen      2   .       65.5    65
    1   random      2   YES     65      65
    1   visit1      2   .       .       65
    1   screen      3   .       .       400
    1   random      3   YES     400     400
    1   visit1      3   .       420     400
```

I used the the following code

```
data want;
set have;
by SUBJID PARAMN;
if first.PARAMN and ABLF=' ' then BASE=.;
if ABLF='YES' then BASE=AVAL;
retain BASE;
run;
```

however when I run this I don't the data to look exactly as I want above

Comment: The RETAIN statement cannot  move data back into the past.  You cannot use it to set the value on the second observation ('random') and have it apply to the first observation ('screen') that has already been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RETAIN does not look like the right tool for this.  RETAIN can only move data forward in the file. It cannot move it backwards.

Looks like there is just one observation with the "BASE" value. So just merge it back onto the data.

```
data want;
  merge have
        have(keep=subjid paramn aval ablf rename=(aval=BASE ablf=xx)
             where=(xx='YES'))
  ;
  by SUBJID PARAMN;
  drop xx;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pro SQL:**

```
proc sql;
   select a.*,b.aval as BASE from have a left join have(drop=visit where=(ablf='YES')) b
   on a.subjid=b.subjid and a.paramn=b.paramn;
quit;
```

**Double do loop:**

```
data want;
    do until(last.visit);
    set have;
    retain temp;
    by subjid paramn notsorted;
    if ablf='YES' then temp=aval;
    end;
    do until(last.visit);
    set have;
    by subjid paramn notsorted;
    base=temp;
    end;
    drop temp;
run;
```